# List of objects to map in java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a class like this

```
ObjectA
id 
type
```

where id is unique but the type can be duplicate so if I have a list of ObjectA like this

```
(id, type) = (1, "A") , (2, "B"), (3, "C"), (4, "A")
```

then I want `Map<type, List<id>>` where 
map is

```
< "A",[1,4],
  "B",[2],
  "C",[3] >
```

It is working with Java 7 but can't find a way to do it in Java 8. In Java 8 I can create key, value pair but not able to create a list if a type is same.

Comment: which code is working with java 7?

Comment: Please post the code causing the problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
yourTypes.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
               ObjectA::getType,
               Collectors.mapping(
                    ObjectA::getId, Collectors.toList()
)))
```

Comment: worked fine for me thanks

Answer (score 16):

Employee list to map

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(new Employee(1, "John",80000));
            list.add(new Employee(2, "Jack", 90000));
            list.add(new Employee(3, "Ricky", 120000));


            // key = id, value - name
            Map<Integer, String> result1 = list.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, Employee::getName));
```

Comment: What if I want to give a constant value instead of `Employee::getName`?

Comment: `Map<Integer, String> result1 = list.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, "constant value here like this"));`

@ArunGowda

Answer (score 6):

Though you got some nice answer. I would like to share another way of doing same. It's when you have to tackle really complex conversions to map.

```
class Student {
    private String name;
    private Integer id;
//getters / setters / constructors
}

            Map<String, List<Integer>> map = Arrays.asList(
            new Student("Jack", 2),
            new Student("Jack", 2),
            new Student("Moira", 4)
    )
            .stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            Student::getName,
                            student -> {
                                List list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                                list.add(student.getId());
                                return list;
                            },
                            (s, a) -> {
                                s.add(a.get(0));
                                return s;
                            }
                    )
            );
```

Notice how complex you could play with value and return the new value accordingly.

toMap parameters are respectively keyMapper function, valueMapper function and merger respectively.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

A way to do it without streams:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(object -> 
    map.computeIfAbsent(object.getType(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
        .add(object.getId()));
```

This uses [`Iterable.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) and [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to iterate the `list` and group its elements (here named `object`) by its `type` attribute, creating a new `ArrayList` if there was no entry for that type in the map yet. Then, the `id` of the object is added to the list.

Comment: *without streams* is going to be your nick soon... :)

Comment: I disagree! I found computeIfAbsent wonderful when it was beyond streams to tackle some scenario.

Comment: Perfect! that is exctly what i was looking for, even without stream is a great answer, thannk you

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Employee(1, "John",80000));
list.add(new Employee(2, "Jack", 90000));
list.add(new Employee(3, "Ricky", 120000));

// key = id, value - name
Map<Integer, String> result = list.stream().collect(
Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, Employee::getName));

If you want to give a constant value instead of name:
// key = id, value - "ABC"
Map<Integer, String> result = list.stream().collect(
Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, emp-> "ABC"));
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

List to Map object

`employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName, Collectors.toList())) .forEach((key,value)->System.out.println("key : "+key+" , value : "+value));`

### output:

key: **Name** : value : **List of employee Object**