# Using stream for Java Enum to generate map

Tags: java, lambda, enums, java-stream

I have a Enum class

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A("A"),
    B("B");

    private final String key;
}
```

And I want to generate a map like this:

```
private Map<MyEnum, MyClass> myMethod(String input) {
    Map<MyEnum, MyClass> result = Maps.newHashMap();
    for (MyEnum enum : MyEnum.values()) {
        Optional<MyClass> value = helper(enum, input);
        value.ifPresent(val -> result.put(enum, val));
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am new to lambda/stream, can we refactor it to something like:

```
private Map<MyEnum, MyClass> myMethod(String input) {
    return MyEnum.values().stream().map(...).collect(Collector.toMap(...));
}
```

I tried to use `Arrays.stream()...`
but at last when I use `collect(Collector.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)`
it has some static vs non-static issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of objects to map in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747537/list-of-objects-to-map-in-java-8)

Comment: also, if you dont show the stack trace, its hard for anyone to know what the static vs non-static issue is. probably you have a static variable that you are using inside a method that is not static

Comment: show some real code instead of ... ... ... inside your stream if you want people to correct whats wrong with your refactored method using streams

Comment: What are you passing to `map()`? I'm guessing it's not a `Function<MyEnum, Map.Entry<MyEnum, MyClass>>`. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
public enum CodeLetter { A, B, C; }
```

```java
Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > map =
        Stream
                .of ( CodeLetter.values ( ) )
                .collect (
                        ( ) -> new EnumMap <> ( CodeLetter.class ) ,
                        ( Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > m , CodeLetter v ) -> m.put ( v , this.helper ( v ) ) ,
                        Map :: putAll
                );
```

## Details

Let's make your example code more concrete. Instead of `MyEnum`, we call that `CodeLetter`. Instead of `MyClass`, we use `java.time.DayOfWeek`.

Firstly, it seems the `key` field is just a distraction, unrelated to your Question. So we reduce that to a simple enum declaration.

```java
public enum CodeLetter { A, B, C; }
```

We provide an implementation for the `helper` class you mention. Pass one of the `CodeLetter` enum objects, get back a `DayOfWeek` object.

```java
DayOfWeek helper ( final CodeLetter codeLetter ) {
    DayOfWeek dow =
            switch ( codeLetter ) {
                case A -> DayOfWeek.SATURDAY;
                case B -> DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
                case C -> null;
            };
    return dow;
}
```

Now implement fully your example method that builds a map.

- We rename that method from `myMethod` to `buildMap`.
- We rename `result` to `map` for clarity.
- We eliminate the argument to that method, as it seems irrelevant.
- There is no such class nor method `Maps.newHashMap`, so we replace that with a specific class that implements `Map`. When you have an enum as your map key, use the highly optimized [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html) class.
- `Optional<MyClass>`, would be `Optional<CodeLetter>` with our new naming. But `Optional` is generally best used only as a return type. In our case here, `EnumMap` allows for map values to be null. So we forgo the `Optional` to use simple null instead.

```java
private Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > buildMap ( ) {
    Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > map = new EnumMap <> ( CodeLetter.class );
    for ( CodeLetter codeLetter : CodeLetter.values ( ) ) {
        DayOfWeek dow = this.helper ( codeLetter );
        map.put ( codeLetter , dow );
    }
    return map;
}
```

Exercise this code.

```java
EnumMapExample app = new EnumMapExample ( );
Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > map = app.buildMap ( );
System.out.println ( "map = " + map );
```

When run:

> map = {A=SATURDAY, B=SUNDAY, C=null}

Good, the code runs successfully.

Back to the thrust of your Question. You seem to want to refactor the `buildMap` method to use a stream rather than our `for` loop. Fair enough. Let's create a `buildMapByStream` method, as an alternate implementation.

To build our map by stream, first get a stream of the values of our key, `CodeLetter`. Then call `collect` on that stream. To the `collect` method we pass a `Collector` implementation. Java provides one via the `Collectors.toMap` method. We pass to the `toMap` method four arguments: a lambda to generate each map key, a lambda to generate each map value, a lambda to resolve any conflicts, and a lambda to construct a resulting `Map` implementation of our choice.

```java
private Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > buildMapByStream ( ) {
    Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > map =
            Stream
                    .of ( CodeLetter.values ( ) )
                    .collect (
                            Collectors.toMap (
                                    ( CodeLetter codeLetter ) -> codeLetter ,
                                    ( CodeLetter codeLetter ) -> this.helper ( codeLetter ) ,
                                    ( DayOfWeek dow1 , DayOfWeek dow2 ) -> dow1 ,
                                    ( ) -> new EnumMap <> ( CodeLetter.class )
                            )
                    );
    return map;
}
```

We can simplify the first two arguments.

- The first argument is a lambda that merely returns the passed object. Java provides a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) implementation that provides the same functionality: [`Function.identity`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#identity()).
- The second argument is a lambda that calls our `helper` method. We can abbreviate that with a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), `this :: helper`.

After those changes our code looks like this:

```java
private Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > buildMapByStream ( ) {
    Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > map =
            Stream
                    .of ( CodeLetter.values ( ) )
                    .collect (
                            Collectors.toMap (
                                    Function.identity ( ) ,
                                    this :: helper ,
                                    ( DayOfWeek dow1 , DayOfWeek dow2 ) -> dow1 ,
                                    ( ) -> new EnumMap <> ( CodeLetter.class )
                            )
                    );
    return map;
}
```

We should be able to consider the job done. Unfortunately, Java 8 through 21 has [a known bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8148463) in `Collectors.toMap` where a `NullPointerException` is thrown when the generated map value is null. See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24630963/642706), and [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24634007/642706) by kajacx.

Fortunately, that Answer presents a workaround to replace the use of `Collectors.toMap`.

```java
private Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > buildMapByStream ( ) {
    Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > map =
            Stream
                    .of ( CodeLetter.values ( ) )
                    .collect (
                            ( ) -> new EnumMap <> ( CodeLetter.class ) ,
                            ( Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > m , CodeLetter v ) -> m.put ( v , this.helper ( v ) ) ,
                            Map :: putAll
                    );
    return map;
}
```

At this point we can exercise our `buildMapByStream` method.

```java
EnumMapExample app = new EnumMapExample ( );
Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > map = app.buildMapByStream ( );
System.out.println ( "map = " + map );
```

> map = {A=SATURDAY, B=SUNDAY, C=null}

That works, job done.

Here is the complete code for your copy-paste convenience.

```java
package work.basil.example.enums;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class EnumMapExample {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        EnumMapExample app = new EnumMapExample ( );
        Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > map = app.buildMapByStream ( );
        System.out.println ( "map = " + map );
    }

    private Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > buildMap ( ) {
        Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > map = new EnumMap <> ( CodeLetter.class );
        for ( CodeLetter codeLetter : CodeLetter.values ( ) ) {
            DayOfWeek dow = this.helper ( codeLetter );
            map.put ( codeLetter , dow );
        }
        return map;
    }

    private Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > buildMapByStream ( ) {
        Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > map =
                Stream
                        .of ( CodeLetter.values ( ) )
                        .collect (
                                ( ) -> new EnumMap <> ( CodeLetter.class ) ,
                                ( Map < CodeLetter, DayOfWeek > m , CodeLetter v ) -> m.put ( v , this.helper ( v ) ) ,
                                Map :: putAll
                        );
        return map;
    }

    DayOfWeek helper ( final CodeLetter codeLetter ) {
        DayOfWeek dow =
                switch ( codeLetter ) {
                    case A -> DayOfWeek.SATURDAY;
                    case B -> DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
                    case C -> null;
                };
        return dow;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the detail explanation, it really helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```java
Map<MyEnum, MyClass> result
    = Stream.of(MyEnum.values())
            .map(x -> Map.entry(x, helper(x, input)))
            .filter(x -> x.getValue().isPresent())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, x -> x.getValue().get()));
```